# All folders, .h and .c files of stdio, stdlib etc?

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I have a custom C compiler that has a dedicated folder "include" where all .h and .c files should go. But it is missing all standard libraries. What is the quickest way to get all the include files for libraries like stdio and stdlib etc on the internet? I found websites offering separate .h or .c files for download, but is there one that offers the full collection of dependencies? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: You should use the header files provided by your custom C compiler. The standard header files defines very often macros and values that are only compatible with a particular version of the compiler and libc. So using the header files from GCC would not necessarily work. You can try coping the stuff from gcc and glibc, but I don't think this will end well.

Comment: @Pablo I see, thank you I will try to copy from GCC and see if it works. (Otherwise its just missing anyway...)

Comment: @Kagaratsch Don't do that. GCC's headers are specific to that compiler.

Comment: @duskwuff yeah, it did not end up working after all, so I removed the files again. Will have to figure it out another way...